# Отменить перенос RichEditBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

При нажатии Enter у меня происходит отправка сообщения и поле очищается

```
private void Clear_Enter(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
            {
                string str;
                Message_BOX.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.None, out str);
                while (str[str.Length - 1] == '\n' || str[str.Length - 1] == '\r')
                    str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
                Message_BOX.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, str);
            }
        }
```

Но перед очисткой все равно идет перенос строки и видна анимация переноса. Как убрать перенос?

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, самый простой и верный способ добиться желаемого эффекта, заключается в создании наследника `RichEditBox` и переопределении метода `OnKeyDown`. Вот как это может выглядеть:

```
public class CustomRichTextBox : RichEditBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // invoked anytime a key is pressed down, independent of focus
        if(e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, "");
            return;
        }
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Мы не пропускаем Enter к обработчику `RichEditBox`, таким образом никакой обработки нажатия этой клавиши не будет, следовательно никакой анимации и прочего Вы не увидите.